# sed: replace strings with variable content

Tags: sed

I'm trying to write a script that finds strings in a certain pattern (`{?varname}`) and replaces them with a corresponding environment variable.

This is what I have so far:

```
function get_env() {
   var=$1
   echo ${!var}
}

sed -e 's/{?\([a-z]*}\)/'$(get_env '\1')'/g' file.txt
```

The function works, e.g. `get_env LOGNAME` --> `dotan`

Sed returns the value of the function, e.g. if I replace the function's content with `echo __$1__` I will get `{?logname}` --> `__LOGNAME__`

However put together it doesn't work. It's like the function always returns an empty string.

I'm not sure what causes the problem here. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not your issue but always quote your variables.  `echo "${!var}"`

Comment: You will not be able to pass the back reference `\1` out of `sed`, back into the shell and into your function, and then get the correct value back from there.

Answer (score 5):

That command line would run `get_env '\1'` in a command substitution, and paste its output on the command line of `sed`. You should probably get an error about that, since `\1` is not a valid name for a variable.

You could use Perl and `s/\{\?([a-z]+)\}/$ENV{$1}/` to do that; `%ENV` is a hash that contains the environment variables:

```
$ export name=you
$ echo "hello {?name}" | perl -pe 's/\{\?([a-z]+)\}/$ENV{$1}/'
hello you
```

(GNU sed has the `e` command to run external programs, but it uses runs the whole pattern space, not just the matching part, so it doesn't seem to fit here too well.)

---

Purely in Bash, if you insist (`setvar.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line ; do
        while [[ $line =~ ^(.*)(\{\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\})(.*)$ ]] ; do
                varname=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
                varname=${varname#"{?"}
                varname=${varname%\}}
                printf -v line "%s%s%s" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${!varname}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        done
        printf "%s\n" "$line" 
done < "${1-/dev/stdin}"

$ echo 'foo {?BASH_VERSION} {?blah} bar' |blah=ABC bash setvar.sh
foo 4.4.12(1)-release ABC bar
```

Comment: good one.. suggestion: `e` modifier not here.. `s/\{\?([a-z]+)\}/$ENV{$1}/` would work too..

Comment: @Sundeep, oh right, it doesn't need that, thanks!

Comment: the `get env '\1'` part works, actually. Like I said, if the function only echos $1, the value stays the same. Anyway, thanks, but I was looking for a solution in pure bash.

Comment: @Dotan, well yes, it works, the shell runs the function once, and passes the output to sed's command line. If the output is `foo`, then `sed` replaces all matches with `foo`. If the output of the function is `\1` then `sed` replaces all matches with the first backreference. And if the function is `get_env() { echo "$1"; }`, it outputs its first argument, so `$(get_env '\1')` outputs `\1`.

Comment: @Dotan, but as you saw and as Kusalananda commented, you can't get the string matched by `sed` back to the shell for the command substitution. That's the reason you're asking this in the first place, isn't it?

Comment: @Dotan, also, you mentioned nothing about the tools you're limited to. A pure Bash solution seems odd to require since you mentioned `sed` in the question title and the tags. But I added a solution in Bash, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with

```
grep -o '{?\S*}' file.txt | sed 's/{?\(.*\)}/\1/' | xargs -I {} sh -c "sed -i -e 's/{?"{}"}/'$"{}"'/' file.txt"
```

To break it down:

- `grep -o '{?\S*}' file.txt` - get all the variables to replace
- `sed 's/{?\(.*\)}/\1/'` - strip the formatting
- `xargs -I {} sh -c "sed -i -e 's/{?"{}"}/'$"{}"'/' file.txt"` - search and replace for each var seprately